# C# Masked Textbox

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, maskedtextbox

When I press a digit at the end of mask string it rejects input which is fine. My question is that is there a way to know which key was pressed when my mask input is rejected? If there is any way kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0):

With the events `MaskInputRejected` and `KeyPress` you can capture the input keys and handle them on input failure like this:

```
    private void maskedTextBox1_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
    {
        var lastKeyChar = _lastKeyChar;
    }

    private void maskedTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        _lastKeyChar = e.KeyChar;
    }
```